# Redirect Custom Post Type from Child Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have created a Custom Post type and its own respective taxonomy.

I have for example this URL structure: http://www.example.com/faq/category/sub-category/test-post/

The same content can also be accessible through this link:
http://www.example.com/faq/category/test-post/

How can I write a rewrite so the second URL is not available especially for google SEO perspective and avoid duplicate content

Answer (score 0):

Your taxonomy is set to `'hierarchical' => true,` do you have the post included in both the parent and child category?

If you untick the parent `category` and only tick `sub-category` then it should use the first URL only.

Comment: Alex, No I don't have in both categories only 1. But Im doing some custom functions in order to get the post and the taxonomy using the same slugs. I am following this post: https://themoonwatch.com/en/2012/custom-permalinks-hierarchical-taxonomies/

Comment: @jojo not sure, if i would work with a solution from 2012.. try to find something more recent..

Comment: @honk31 - Do you have any solution for what I would like to achieve? I wan to create a custom WordPress Rewrite Rule to Combine Taxonomy and Post Type with unlimited number of taxonomies

Comment: @Jojo please create a new question here on se with all your goals. paste in the code, that you have and lets try to solve it..